# Chrome ignores font weight with font size larger than 1.2em

Tags: css, google-chrome

I just updated my Chrome browser and for some strange reason, the headings of my website look thinner. I did some research and the problem occurs when the font-weight is larger than 1.2em. 1.2em and smaller work fine.

System:

- MacBook Pro Version 10.15.2 Catalina
- Google Chrome Version 81.0.4044.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)

My CSS:

```
body, button, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

h1, .h1, h2, .h2, h3, .h3, h4, .h4, h5, .h5, h6, .h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

h1, .h1 {
    font-size: 1.65em;
}
```

Research:

- The problem has nothing to do with font smoothing (I double checked),
  but I think it might has something to do with the font, Because when
  I remove `-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont` the problem disappears.
- It is not only related to headings, but it also occurs on other elements like buttons with a bigger font size than 1.2em.

Font-size: 1.3em:

[image: Font size: 1.3em]

Font-size: 1.2em:

[image: Font size: 1.2em]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a Chrome problem and will probably be resolved in next Chrome updates https://www.bram.us/2020/04/09/chrome-vs-blinkmacsystemfont-when-bold-is-not-bold/